# Как передаётся brace-init-list в std::vector::push_back?

Tags: c++, stl

У меня есть `std::vector<std::string>`.
Если я в него делаю `push_back({ '1',  '2' })`, то всё ок.
Но если сделать в него `emplace_back(std::move({ '1', '2' }))`, то код не скомпилируется, хотя, судя по реализации push_back, он делает буквально то же самое.

```
_CONSTEXPR20 void push_back(_Ty&& _Val) {
    // insert by moving into element at end, provide strong guarantee
    emplace_back(_STD move(_Val));
}
```

Каких нюансов я не понимаю? И каким образом brace-init-list доходит до конструктора строки в векторе при использовании push_back? Ведь brace-init-list не является объектом, как на него можно rvalue reference делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы `std::move({'1', '2'})` сработал, компилятору нужно угадать шаблонный параметр `move` (тип параметра функции) из типа `{'1', '2'}`. А у фигурных скобок нет типа<sup>1</sup> - поэтому здесь ошибка.

Зато в `push_back(_Ty &&)` тип параметра известен заранее (из шаблонного параметра вектора), поэтому при вызове из фигурных скобок создается временный объект этого типа.

> brace-init-list не является объектом, как на него можно rvalue reference делать?

Ссылка не на него, а на временный объект, который из него создается.

---

<sup>1</sup> Нет, тип не `std::initializer_list<char>`. Это заметнее на вот таком примере:

```
struct A {int x; std::string y;};
std::vector<A> a;
a.push_back({1, "2"}); // Явно не `initializer_list<??>`.
```

Comment: Так ведь тип у временного объекта в move такой же, как в push_back, и этот тип известен заранее на этапе компиляции. И компилятор также мог бы в шаблон move подставить этот тип. Кстати, а что это за тип? Как он называется?

Comment: *"тип у временного объекта в move"* В смысле у аргумента, фигурных скобок? Как я уже сказал, у них нет типа.